# Difference in placement of "return"

Tags: python, return

I'm currently learning how to code and I've encountered an issue with the following use of the return function:

```
    unionFind = UnionFind(n)
    
    for A, B in edges:
        if not unionFind.union(A, B):
            return False

    return True
```

When I put return True with no indents, I am able to get the result of False. However, if I were to do the same with this:

```
    unionFind = UnionFind(n)
    
    for A, B in edges:
        if not unionFind.union(A, B):
            return False
        return True
```

I instead receive True only. This is the same with the following:

```
    unionFind = UnionFind(n)
    
    for A, B in edges:
        if not unionFind.union(A, B):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I've checked multiple online sources and I can't seem to understand how the return function behaves in this scenario (is it affected by the for loop or the if condition) and would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Nitpick: `return` is not a function, it's a keyword.

Comment: if you place return inside for loop then the first case which does not match in `if not unionFind.union(A, B)` will return the function as `True` the loop will terminate, hence you are receiving `True`

Comment: If the first couple `A, B` give `False` for `not unionFind.union(A, B)`  and the second give `False` you will indeed have this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, you put the `return True` outside the `for` loop. It means that all iterations must not execute the `return False` so that it will `return True` at the end after the loop. However, you get `False` as a result because at least one iteration the condition is `True`, which makes it `return False` before the loop ends.

```
for A, B in edges:
    if not unionFind.union(A, B):
        return False

return True
```

With the same logical thinking, you changed the return placement to either

```
for A, B in edges:
    if not unionFind.union(A, B):
        return False
    return True
```

or

```
for A, B in edges:
    if not unionFind.union(A, B):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

The execution of the each iteration in the `for` loop will check your `if` condition whether the condition is `True`. If the condition is `True` then you will reach the `return False` and the loop ends. Otherwise, the condition is not met so the program will execute `return True` instead. This also makes the loop ends because of the `return` statement. Please note that these two cases will always execute only the first iteration of its `for` loop because it will `return` either `True` or `False` right away at the end. So, the reason that you always get `return True` with these two cases is because the first iteration does not meet the condition, which leads to `return True`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not how the return statement behaves. It is about the code scopes.
When you're putting the statement without indents, then the `return True` is outside the `for` loop scope, and it will be reached only after looping through all the `A` and `B` couples and only if the `not unionFind.union(A, B)` condition does not hold for all the couples.

If you're putting the `return True` with the indent or in the `else` statement, it will be reached in the `for` scope, which means that only the first couple of `A` and `B` will be checked.

I hope it makes sense to you.